# Visual Studio 2015 just debug once, then i have to restart VS

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I'm a PHP developer, but recently I have to work with Visual Studio in a C# application. I don't know much about C#, just had a few experiences with it, and the problem is when I try to run/debug my code it works only for the first time. If I change ANY piece of code anywhere in the code the project won't launch anymore, all it does when I click "Debug" is open Google Chrome for me and there it hangs awaiting for "localhost" forever... This issue is driving me nuts, I can't program well if I have to restart Visual Studio whenever I change some code.

I have tried a lot of things that I found here and on Google, but nothing helped. I have fully repaired VS 2015, didn't work. Then I reinstalled it and still not working.

Comment: A few questions for you.  Have you tried any other browser besides Chrome?  Do you multiple tabs open in Chrome or have you tried with just one tab open?  Do you have "Show all files" enabled in the solution explorer?  Sometimes this causes issues if there are large amounts of files/folders unused by the project but still sitting in the same directory as your project.

Comment: Do you have any breakpoints set in the application? And when you look at Visual Studio, does it allow you to click a "Continue" button in green near the top?

Comment: @Ageonix i tried Firefox, same issue, i tried with only one tab.. as for the "Show all files" its disabled.

Comment: @mason right now i have no breakpoints setted, even when i have some setted stills not working, and no it will not allow me "Continue" the debug, but there is the "pause" and "stop" button that i can click normally.